# Java : cannot connect to other computer through ad-hoc when using socket

Tags: java, sockets, adhoc

I have created a simple game, that two computer connect together. I have tested on same computer, no problem. When I create ad-hoc network (in Windows 7). One computer is a server, it created successfully :

```
ssock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
sock = ssock.accept();
```

And one computer is client:

```
sock = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
```

When run to this line. I received this error :

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:375)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:189)   at
>   com.controller.MainController$GameObject.(MainController.java:78)
>     at com.controller.MainController$3.run(MainController.java:180)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Please help me point out, what wrong here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a firewall (OS firewall or network firewall) in between? Is server reachable?

Comment: With what did you replace the hostname "localhost" on the client when you transfered the server to another machine? ("localhost" means "this machine", not "a machine on the local network")

Comment: @Philipp I don't understand you so much. Does it means we shouldn't use `localhost` but other name ?

Comment: @SJuan76 how to know server reachable ? But, when I connect ad-hoc of these two computer, I can play another game together, does it matter ? thanks :)

Comment: Yes, 'localhost' is the name of *this* host. If you want to talk to another host you have to use its name, not your own.

Comment: The most basic check would be, from the client computer, do `telnet [remoteComputer] [serverPort]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
sock = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
```

the first argument "localhost" is the hostname of the machine you want to connect to. "localhost" always means the current machine. When the server runs on another machine, you have to tell the socket where to find it.

You need to replace "localhost" with the IP address or the hostname of the other machine. When you don't know these, follow these steps on the server machine:

- Start -> Run
- enter `cmd` and press enter to open the command shell
- enter `ipconfig` in the command shell and press enter

You will now see configuration information about all network adapters on the machine, including their IP addresses.

Comment: But, if I create game for LAN purpose, so, the server is unknown (it depend on who create server). So, does have any difference way to communicate between two computers in ad-hoc ?

Comment: Well, you could check the IP address and subnet mask of the local machine and then try to connect to every single IP address in that subnet. I don't know which subnet size windows ad-hoc networks use, but when it's just a /24 network (which would make sense, as noone in their right mind would use ad-hoc networks for hundreds of machines), you just have to check 255 IP addresses, which is still feasible.

Comment: I just found out that windows ad-hoc networks use the IP network 169.254.0.0/16, which means that you have to check 65536 IPs for running servers. This could take a few minutes (or seconds when you parallelize it), but could still be more convenient for the users than finding out and entering the IP by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to replacing "localhost" by desired IP address you myst remrmber to check if pointed ports are opoened on firewalls.